# Strtok_r on pipe command not giving output

Tags: c, shell

I am writing a custom shell in C. I want to include piping functionality, so I want to tokenise based on pipe symbols.

I seem to have made a mistake here, as there is no output when I try to print the tokens out.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/resource.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/utsname.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<pwd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

#define MAX_NO_OF_CMD_ELEMENTS (10)
#define MAX_NO_OF_PIPE_ELEMENTS (10)

void main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    int i;
    printf("in piping\n");
    int pipe_num[100] = {0};
    char * pipe_cmd[MAX_NO_OF_PIPE_ELEMENTS];
    char *token, *end_str;
    for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
    {   
        pipe_num[i]++;
        token = strtok_r(argv[i], "|", &end_str);
        pipe_cmd[pipe_num[i]] = token;
        while(token!=NULL)
        {
            pipe_num[i]++;
            token = strtok_r(NULL,"|",&end_str);
            pipe_cmd[pipe_num[i]] = strdup(token);
            printf("%s %s\n",pipe_cmd[pipe_num[i]],token);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You have reversed the arguments to `main()`.  The argument count must come first, then the pointer to the argument values.

Comment: Oops. But this is another function in my actual program. But I will fix it anyway.

Comment: You cannot have two external functions with the same name in the same program.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It is named differently. Now when I run the code it gives me a segfault `strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
106 ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.` according to gdb. But I have read that this is a harmless error.

Comment: Also when I change the strdup to strcpy, the program prints `in piping` and exits.

Comment: The "no such file or directory" part may be harmless.  The segfault certainly is not.  In any case, I have suspicions about what may be going on, but we really need a [mcve] to address your question satisfactorily.

Comment: But this code, when copied and compiled, does run.

Comment: Then I've lost you.  What is the question?

Comment: I do not know what causes the segfault though. I means it runs till the print statement and then exits.

Comment: Is there something about "we really need a [mcve]" that requires further explanation?

Comment: After `token = strtok_r(NULL,"|",&end_str);`, add `if (token == NULL) break;` or re-write the loop.